# Как проверить, что в лонг моде rsp mod 16 = 8?

Tags: c++, ассемблер

"Проверить, что в лонг моде rsp mod 16 = 8."  что это значит и как это сделать?

Answer (score 3):

Я подозреваю, что вас просят проверить, выровнен ли стек по границе 16 байт. Возможно, это бывает кому-то нужно для целей эффективности работы некоторых инструкций процессора. Вершина стека находится в `rsp`, потому она должна быть кратной 16. Проверить можно, например, так (пишу из головы, не компилировал):

```
mov rax, rsp
and rax, 15
jz .aligned ; Перейти куда-то, если остаток от деления на 16 равен 0.
```

Соответственно, для проверки на 8, можно написать

```
mov rax, rsp
and rax, 15
cmp rax, 8
je .aligned ; Перейти куда-то, если остаток от деления на 16 равен 8.
```

Comment: Хм, но в вопросе `=8`, а не `=0`.

Comment: Да, спасибо за поправку. Я пока ответ писал, забыл вопрос :)

Comment: Благодарю. то что нужно. если можно, то скажите еще как его выровнять, т.е. сделать кратным 8 в данном случае.

Comment: Ну, следует затолкать в стек столько байтов, сколько не хватает для кратности.

Comment: ок, спасибо, с вашей помощью разобрался.